# Log in and fetch data from https site (that requires javascript!), using server-side scripting

Tags: javascript, https, server-side

I am trying to get data from my school web portal, that requires logging in, and the login page requires javascript. I need to do this log in by some sort of server-side scripting, preferably php...
Does anyone have any creative solutions? I know php does not support javascript...

Answer (score -1):

use live http headers firefox plugin to see exactly what post fields are sent to the script , and then emulate that with cURL

--Viva Egypt

Comment: cUrl cannot login to a website with javascript... please read the question... this is not a question of how to use php/curl... i need a way to visit a https javascript enabled site on my server